# Random forest accuracy in weka

Tags: random-forest

I am applying random forest algorithm in weka. Its giving 100% of accuracy with training , testing and cross validation. i just wanted to know is there any problem in my dataset due to which its giving 100% accuracy?

Comment: Can you give some more information about the data? It is hard to tell if something is wrong with such limited information

Comment: i am unable to attach my dataset. please tell me how to attach. i am new here.